# Auth::guard('user')->user() is null in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, guard

I'm trying to pass to all templates current user object like this:

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        view()->share('usr', Auth::guard('user'));
    }
}
```

Every controller is extended by Controller. But if i try to dump `Auth::guard('user')->user()` Laravel returns null, although I am logged in. Moreover when i pass this variable into template, `{{ $usr->user() }}` returns current user. What I've done wrong?

my config/auth.php

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'user',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
'guards' => [
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'user',
        ],
    ],
'providers' => [
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
    ],
```

Kernel.php

```
         protected $middleware = [
     \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
 ];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        //\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```

my own function to log in:

```
public function authorizes(Request $request)
{
        $this->validate($request, [
        'login' => 'required|max:50',
        'password' => 'required|max:50'
    ]);

        $credentials = $request->only(['login', 'password' ]);
        $remember = $request->get('remember', false) == 1 ? true : false;

    if ($this->guard->attempt( $credentials, $remember)) {
        $user = $this->guard->user();
        $user->last_login = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $user->save();
        return redirect()->route( 'homepage' )->withSuccess(trans('app.login.success'));
    }
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors(trans('app.wrong.credentials'));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Laravel 5.3 you should change your controller constructor like so to make this work (assuming you use at least Laravel 5.3.4):

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        view()->share('usr', Auth::guard('user'));

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

You can see this change described in [Upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0):

> In previous versions of Laravel, you could access session variables or
>   the authenticated user in your controller's constructor. This was
>   never intended to be an explicit feature of the framework. In Laravel
>   5.3, you can't access the session or authenticated user in your controller's constructor because the middleware has not run yet.
>
> As an alternative, you may define a Closure based middleware directly
>   in your controller's constructor. Before using this feature, make sure
>   that your application is running Laravel 5.3.4

Comment: This is the correct answer, literally ran into this yesterday!

Answer (score 2):

Try to do this:

```
view()->share('usr', Auth::user());
```

Or this:

```
view()->share('usr', auth()->user());
```

Comment: null in both cases

Comment: Are you sure you're logged in? Please double check this. Did you change sessions related functionality or something? Did you add `web` middleware to your routes manually?

Comment: in other controllers, which are extended by this Controller it returns current user... 100% that im logged in!

`Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
// all my routes
}
Route::get('/login', [ 'as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@login' ] );
Route::get('/logout', [ 'as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'AuthController@logout' ] );
Route::post('/login', [ 'as' => 'authorize', 'uses' => 'AuthController@authorizes' ] );`

Answer (score 0):

Frist check if user is logged or not, then share the current user as:

```
public function __construct()
{
    if (auth()->check()) {
        $this->currentUser = auth()->user();
        View::share('currentUser', $this->currentUser);
    } else {
      // you can redirect the user to login page.
    }
}
```

Comment: but in Controller it always returns false. In other controllers which are extended by Controller, this returns true

Answer (score 0):

In your case there are two things to consider

1. To get actual user model you should do `Auth::guard('user')->user()`
2. `Auth::user()` is actually not yet initialized when `view()->share()` is called, see https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6130

Therefore you could rather use view composer. In `boot` method of your `AppServiceProvider` add:

```
\View::composer('*', function ($view) {
    $view->with('usr', \Auth::guard('user')->user());
});
```